# Отключение обортки шорткодов в wordpress unyson

Tags: php, wordpress

Здравствуйте, вопрос тем, кто разрабатывает сайты на вордпресс и знаком с плагином Unyson.
Имеются свёрстанные страницы и нужно посадить на wordpress с возможностью изменения контента, нашёл такой плагин как Unyson, прочитал всю документацию, написал нужные шорткоды и вроде бы всё нормально.
Но тут оказалось, что Unyson оборачивает все шорткоды в визуальном редакторе в секции потом в строки и колонки(section .row .col-xs-12 только свои), от которых вся верстка едет.
Пример:
В пустую страницу вставляю шорткод Hello world
Он оборачивается в:
<div class="fw-page-builder-content">
    <div class="fw-row">
        <div class="fw-col-xs-12">
            Hello world
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
Вопрос как убрать эту обёртку с возможностью оставлять только шорткоды
Если в плагине это не предусмотрена, посоветуйте пожалуйста плагин для редактирование контента, в котором это есть.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Не работал но мож переопределить эти классы в css? p.s. В css и js не силён...

Comment: * [Как изменить `.fw-...` классы на bootstrap](http://manual.unyson.io/en/latest/extension/builder/index.html#changing-the-grid) * [Конфиг для отключения авто-генерации секций, строк и колонок](https://github.com/ThemeFuse/Unyson-PageBuilder-Extension/blob/v1.6.1/config.php)